# Http request from android app to server

Tags: android

I am trying to send name and surname to my server from an android app. But unable to get the connection. I have used most of the codes available, but none of them are working. Below is the snapshot of my code:

```
private void nextActivity(Profile profile) {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;

    try {
        con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("**********/index.php")).openConnection();//not written the url for privacy concern
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();
        con.getOutputStream().write(("name=" + profile.getFirstName()).getBytes());
        con.getOutputStream().write(("surname=" + profile.getLastName()).getBytes());
    }
    catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (profile != null) {
        Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        main.putExtra("name", profile.getFirstName());
        main.putExtra("surname", profile.getLastName());
        main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200, 200).toString());
        startActivity(main);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I hope you are using an AsyncTask here...

Comment: Check for internet permission & try pinging your server

Comment: which exception do you get?

Comment: i have already included internet permission

Comment: I am not getting any exception or error

Comment: Is your test device and server in the same network?

Comment: no my test device and server are not in same network. I am using hostinger.in as server

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant to your question, but you have a `}` too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this code as AsyncTask and my problem is solved.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            String id = params[0], firstname = params[1], lastname = params[2];

            URL url = new URL("http://*******index.php");


            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8") +
                    "&" + URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(firstname, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("surname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lastname, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ...
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in your code and try.

```
con.getOutputStream().flush();
con.getOutputStream().close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the data using URLEncoder first and than write with output stream.